# stroller (turbogears) not working

Tags: python-2.7, e-commerce, shopping-cart, turbogears2, satchless

I'am trying to build an e-commerce website using turbogears. Initially I modified the tgapp-photos to make the items come on the page properly. But then I find it difficult to make cart from the scratch and hence thought to use stroller. However, when I'am plugging it in the config.py file, all of a sudden my app stops. And moreover it is not showing any error too, it just stops. Could someone please tell me what wrong am I doing. 
Can I use satchless or shoppingCart in the turbogears framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stroller is a pretty old project that is not maintained anymore. The reason why it was not working for you is that it was still pending some changes required to make it compatible with TG2.3+, it was compatible only with <=2.2. And so was looking for some Pylons imports.

To solve your problem I just released `stroller 0.5.1` which is now compatible with TG2.3, please keep in mind that as it is a pretty old project it depends on `ToscaWidgets1` and doesn't work with TW2 so you should:

- Remove `tw2.forms` dependency from your project `setup.py`
- Uninstall `tw2.core` and `tw2.forms` from your virtualenv (if they are available sprox will use tw2 and some forms in stroller won't work)
- change `base_config.prefer_toscawidgets2` in `base_config.use_toscawidgets = True`

Those are the required step to disable ToscaWidgets2 in your project and revert back to ToscaWidgets1 which is required by stroller.